# Change position of buttons JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

i wanted to change the button that displays on the top of an html page

```
<div class='play'>
    <input id="play" type="button" value="Play" onclick="mode('play');startSlideshow();" />
</div>
<div class='pause'>     
    <input id="pause" type="button" value="Pause" onclick="mode('pause');startSlideshow();" />
</div>

<style>
    .play{
        position: absolute;
        top:452px;
        left: 85px          
    }
    .pause{
        position: absolute;
        top:452px;
        left: 85px          
    }
</style>
```

so far, this show the pause button in front of the play button, that's ok,  i tried to move the button and make it hidden but it dosent move, i also tried to change the style.position of the pause button but it wont move anyway

```
else if(smode=="pause")
{
    var pau = document.getElementById('pause'); 
    pau.setAttribute('style', 'top:100px;left:150px;');
    document.getElementById("pause").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: you want to move the button or you want to toggle between play and pause? In other words: do you want to click on play and make it disappear while pause appear?

Comment: Made a Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/9asub0ns/, your code seems to work fine. Of course the button is hidden, so you don't see the new position...
Are you sure, that you enter the 'else if' block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code will toggle your play and pause button, so only one will show at a time.

```js
function mode(action) {
  
  console.log(action);
  if(action == 'play') {
    document.getElementById('play').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('pause').style.display = "block";
  }
  if(action == 'pause') {
    document.getElementById('play').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('pause').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='play'>
    <input id="play" type="button" value="Play" onclick="mode('play');" />
</div>
<div class='pause'>     
    <input id="pause" style="display:none;" type="button" value="Pause" onclick="mode('pause');" />
</div>
```